# SharePoint script not playing with Rundeck

Tags: xml, powershell, sharepoint, rundeck

I have a powershell script which works fine in ISE however in RunDeck when I run it from a file I get the following error

The string is missing the terminator: '.
09:19:34                + CategoryInfo          : ParserError: (:) [], ParentContainsErrorRecordException
09:19:34                + FullyQualifiedErrorId : TerminatorExpectedAtEndOfString
09:19:34
09:19:34            'mCd'' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
09:19:34            operable program or batch file.
09:19:34            Result: 1

I don't understand what is wrong? Is this just a limitation of RunDeck? The powershell script does contain XML. I have even tried putting the XML contents in a spereate XML file and using get-content however some thing. Here is the code (I am aware of the spelling mistakes, that is "fine")

```
Param(
  [Parameter(Mandatory=$true,Position=0)]
  [string]$pass,
  [Parameter(Mandatory=$true)]
  [string]$teamSiteTitel

)

#Credentials for Service Account
Set-Location "\\Server\c$\admin_apps\scripts\SP_IS"

#Credentials for Service Account
$credentialXml = Get-Content -Path .\cred.xml
$credential = @"
$credentialXml
"@
$tenantName =Select-Xml -Content $credential -XPath "//tenant" | foreach {$_.node.InnerXML}
$username =Select-Xml -Content $credential -XPath "//username" | foreach {$_.node.InnerXML}
$password= ConvertTo-SecureString $pass -AsPlainText -Force
$cred = New-Object -TypeName System.Management.Automation.PSCredential -argumentlist $username, $password 

$rootSite =Select-Xml -Content $credential -XPath "//rootSite" | foreach {$_.node.InnerXML}

# Connect to to Office 365
try{
Connect-PnPOnline -Url ("https://{0}-admin.sharepoint.com/" -f $tenantName) -Credential $cred  
write-host "Info: Connected succesfully to Office 365" -foregroundcolor green
}
catch{
write-host "Error: Could not connect to Office 365" -foregroundcolor red
Break new-SPOnlineSite
}

#Connect to the Site Collection
try{
write-host "Connect to site collection"
Connect-PnPOnline –Url ("https://{0}.sharepoint.com/" -f $tenantName) –Credentials $cred
}catch{
write-host "Error: Could not connect to site 365" -foregroundcolor red
$tenantName
}
#Load SharePoint CSOM Assemblies
[System.Reflection.Assembly]::LoadWithPartialName("Microsoft.SharePoint.Client") | Out-Null
[System.Reflection.Assembly]::LoadWithPartialName("Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.Runtime") | Out-Null

#TeamSite parameter 
#$teamSiteTitel = Read-Host -Prompt "Please enter the Teamsite Titel"
$template = "STS#0"
$pagesLibrary = "Pages"
$PageName="HomePage"
$PageTemplate = "CompanyName2ColumnsPageLayout"

#Create the new team site
$ParentSiteUrl = $rootSite+ "/InternalServices/"
#$ParentSiteUrl = Read-Host -Prompt "Please enter the Teamsite Parent Url"
#Connect to the Site Collection
write-host "Connect to Parent site"
Connect-PnPOnline –Url $ParentSiteUrl –Credentials $cred

Write-Output "Creating new Team Site"
$NewWeb = New-PnPWeb -Title $teamSiteTitel -Url $teamSiteTitel -Template $template -BreakInheritance
$SiteUrl= $NewWeb.Url

##Enable The Push Notifications feature
#Write-Output "Activating Notifications feature"
#Enable-PnPFeature -Identity 41e1d4bf-b1a2-47f7-ab80-d5d6cbba3092 -Scope Web

#Connect to the new team site
Write-Output "Connecting to new Team Site"
Connect-PnPOnline -Url $SiteUrl -Credentials $cred

#create Groups
Write-Output "creating groups"
$ownerGroupName = $teamSiteTitel + "_Owners"
$CompanyNameAllName = "CompanyName_Allnew"

New-PnPGroup -Title $ownerGroupName -ErrorAction SilentlyCont
New-PnPGroup -Title $CompanyNameAllName -ErrorAction SilentlyCont

#Set group permission, owner = full control, member = control
Write-Output "Setting group permissions"
Set-PnPGroupPermissions -Identity $ownerGroupName -AddRole 'Edit' -Web (Get-PnPWeb)
Set-PnPGroupPermissions -Identity $CompanyNameAllName -AddRole 'Contribute' -Web (Get-PnPWeb)

#Add team site owner to owner group
Write-Output "Adding Owner to group"
Add-PnPUserToGroup -LoginName $username -Identity $ownerGroupName

#Activate the "publishing" feature
Write-Output "Activating publishing feature"
Enable-PnPFeature -Identity 94c94ca6-b32f-4da9-a9e3-1f3d343d7ecb -Scope Web

##Remove Getting Started and Site feed Webpart
Write-Output "Removing Getting Started Webpart"
Remove-PnPWebPart -Title "Get started with your site" -ServerRelativePageUrl "/SitePages/Home.aspx"
Remove-PnPWebPart -Title "Site Feed" -ServerRelativePageUrl "/SitePages/Home.aspx"

#Deactivate "Sit Feed" feature
Write-Output "Deactivate Site Feed feature"
Disable-PnPFeature -Identity 15a572c6-e545-4d32-897a-bab6f5846e18 -Scope Web

#Add Content type
Write-Output "Adding ContenType"
Add-PnPContentTypeToList -List $pagesLibrary -ContentType "CompanyNamePage" -DefaultContentType
Add-PnPContentTypeToList -List "Financials" -ContentType "CompanyNameDocument" -DefaultContentType

#Add Publishing page
Write-Output "Adding Publishing page"
Add-PnPPublishingPage -PageName $PageName -Title $PageName -PageTemplateName $PageTemplate -Publish 

#Set the new Page as home page
Set-PnPHomePage -RootFolderRelativeUrl ("{0}/{1}.aspx" -f $pagesLibrary,$PageName)
$UrlHomePage = $NewWeb.ServerRelativeUrl + "/" + $pagesLibrary + "/" +$PageName +".aspx"

#CheckOut The Page
Set-PnPFileCheckedOut -Url $UrlHomePage

#Adding Documents Webpart
Write-Output "Adding Documents Webpart"
$scriptP= "
    <webParts>
  <webPart xmlns='http://schemas.microsoft.com/WebPart/v3'>
    <metaData>
      <type name='Microsoft.SharePoint.WebPartPages.ScriptEditorWebPart, Microsoft.SharePoint, Version=16.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=71e9bce111e9429c' />
      <importErrorMessage>Cannot import this Web Part.</importErrorMessage>
    </metaData>
    <data>
      <properties>
        <property name='ExportMode' type='exportmode'>All</property>
        <property name='HelpUrl' type='string' />
        <property name='Hidden' type='bool'>False</property>
        <property name='Description' type='string'>Allows authors to insert HTML snippets or scripts.</property>
        <property name='Content' type='string'>
&lt;script type='text/javascript'(&gt;);
Function SP.SOD.executeFunc {('sp.js'), ('SP.ClientContext')}
Function SP.SOD.executeFunc {('sp.search.js', 'Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.Search.Query')}
alightContentSearch('latesDocuments', 'path:\''+_spPageContextInfo.webAbsoluteUrl+''\''NOT FileType:html NOT Filetype:aspx', 'Title', 'LatestDocuments', '5', ([String]{property: 'LastModifiedTime', DESC: 1}));
&lt;/script(&gt;);
&lt;div id='latesDocuments'(&gt;);&lt;/div(&gt;);</property>
        <property name='CatalogIconImageUrl' type='string' />
        <property name='Title' type='string'>Latest Documents</property>
        <property name='AllowHide' type='bool'>True</property>
        <property name='AllowMinimize' type='bool'>True</property>
        <property name='AllowZoneChange' type='bool'>True</property>
        <property name='TitleUrl' type='string' />
        <property name='ChromeType' type='chrometype'>TitleOnly</property>
        <property name='AllowConnect' type='bool'>True</property>
        <property name='Width' type='unit' />
        <property name='Height' type='unit' />
        <property name='HelpMode' type='helpmode'>Navigate</property>
        <property name='AllowEdit' type='bool'>True</property>
        <property name='TitleIconImageUrl' type='string' />
        <property name='Direction' type='direction'>NotSet</property>
        <property name='AllowClose' type='bool'>True</property>
        <property name='ChromeState' type='chromestate'>Normal</property>
      </properties>
    </data>
  </webPart>
</webParts>"


Add-PnPWebPartToWebPartPage -ServerRelativePageUrl $UrlHomePage -XML $scriptP -ZoneId "LeftCol" -ZoneIndex 1


#CheckIn The Page
Set-PnPFileCheckedIn -Url $UrlHomePage

#Site URL
Write-Output "Team Site Url is :" $SiteUrl
```

Comment: Can you share your job definition to check how do you call the PowerShell script?

Answer (score 0):

Call your PowerShell script (inline or external) clicking on "Advanced" button and set "powershell.exe" at "Invocation String" textbox and "ps1" at "File Extension" textbox, click on "Save" and then on "Create" to save your job.

Here a Job-Def that works using local scripts and remote scripts:

```
<joblist>
  <job>
    <defaultTab>nodes</defaultTab>
    <description></description>
    <dispatch>
      <excludePrecedence>true</excludePrecedence>
      <keepgoing>false</keepgoing>
      <rankOrder>ascending</rankOrder>
      <successOnEmptyNodeFilter>false</successOnEmptyNodeFilter>
      <threadcount>1</threadcount>
    </dispatch>
    <executionEnabled>true</executionEnabled>
    <id>6d0867aa-fa70-44fb-b6de-d0eed06fd0dd</id>
    <loglevel>INFO</loglevel>
    <name>ScriptWINDOWS</name>
    <nodeFilterEditable>false</nodeFilterEditable>
    <nodefilters>
      <filter>name: windows</filter>
    </nodefilters>
    <nodesSelectedByDefault>true</nodesSelectedByDefault>
    <scheduleEnabled>true</scheduleEnabled>
    <sequence keepgoing='false' strategy='node-first'>
      <command>
        <fileExtension>ps1</fileExtension>
        <scriptargs />
        <scriptfile>/home/user/Rundeck/ver/3.1.2/hello.ps1</scriptfile>
        <scriptinterpreter>powershell.exe</scriptinterpreter>
      </command>
      <command>
        <exec>powershell.exe c:\users\myuser\myscript.ps1</exec>
      </command>
    </sequence>
    <uuid>6d0867aa-fa70-44fb-b6de-d0eed06fd0dd</uuid>
  </job>
</joblist>
```

Also, check how do you define your windows node, take a look to [this](https://github.com/rundeck/rundeck/issues/3144#issuecomment-376128163). [Here](https://github.com/rundeck-plugins/py-winrm-plugin#node-definition-example) you have a good example.

Comment: I am already calling the script via PS1 file in rundeck. I have also tried inline script. Both have the same result.

Comment: Check how do you configure your Windows box in your node definition: https://github.com/rundeck/rundeck/issues/3144#issuecomment-376128163 & https://github.com/rundeck-plugins/py-winrm-plugin#node-definition-example (I updated my answer).

Answer (score 0):

Careful with @ signs with inline scripts, they are placeholders for rundeck variables.

I have a rule of thumb with inline powershell scripts with rundeck containing "@`s". 
Search and replace all @ with a @@. It will make your life easier.

Sure your code editor wont agree, I tend to keep two copies of a script. The final copy I can edit and the @@ sanitized version loaded into rundeck.

There are rundeck documentation detailing this, on mobile, I'll update the post later if no one beats me to it.

Edit:
try updating this bit to:

```
$credential = @@"
$credentialXml
"@@
```

[Behavior explanation:](https://docs.rundeck.com/docs/manual/job-options.html#escaped-values)

Comment: I have tried the double @ instead of the singular and unfortunatley I get the same result.