The rundeck is unable to execute powershell script with import-module or unable to find the module to the target server
The rundeck is unable to execute powershell script with import-module even I install the 'Microsoft.Online.SharePoint.PowerShell' module in the target server.

[ERROR ] Execution finished with the following error (winrm-exec.py:332)[root]
[ERROR ] Import-Module : The specified module 'Microsoft.Online.SharePoint.PowerShell' was not loaded because no valid module file was found in any module directory.

I try to remove 'Import-Module Microsoft.Online.SharePoint.PowerShell -Verbose' command but I'm getting this error.

[ERROR ] Execution finished with the following error (winrm-exec.py:332)[root]
[ERROR ] Connect-SPOService : The term 'Connect-SPOService' is not recognized as the name of a cmdlet, function, script file,
or operable program. Check the spelling of the name, or if a path was included, verify that the path is correct and
try again.

I already install ' Microsoft.Online.SharePoint.PowerShell' module in the target server but still getting an issue.
Microsoft.Online.SharePoint.PowerShell
Here's my code:
Set-ExecutionPolicy RemoteSigned -Scope Process -Force
[Net.ServicePointManager]::SecurityProtocol = [Net.SecurityProtocolType]::Tls12

#endregion
$username = "user_name"
$password = "password"
$siteUrl = "https://xxxx.sharepoint.com/"
# Connect to Azure AD
$cred = New-Object -TypeName System.Management.Automation.PSCredential -argumentlist $username, $(convertto-securestring $password -asplaintext -force)
Connect-SPOService -Url $siteUrl -Credential $cred -ModernAuth $true -AuthenticationUrl https://login.microsoftonline.com/organizations -WarningAction SilentlyContinue


Hi, could you share the Rundeck job definition to take a look? also, can you double-check that you have that module installed following this? https://www.sharepointdiary.com/2016/11/import-module-specified-module-microsoft-online-sharepoint-powershell-was-not-loaded.html

Hi @MegaDrive68k, please check 'Microsoft.Online.SharePoint.PowerShell' link. I post the screenshot that the module is installed in the target server.

What about the job definition? https://docs.rundeck.com/docs/learning/tutorial/terminology.html#job-definition Can you share it to take a look? Also, ensure you're not facing a double-hop scenario: https://stackoverflow.com/a/63618033/10426011. Additionally take a look at these answers: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58640044/sharepoint-script-not-playing-with-rundeck. Regards!

I can't give you the details of the job definition since it was confidential. Can I know what specific you want to check in the job definition?

Is your job trying to do a double hop? like this: https://github.com/rundeck-plugins/py-winrm-plugin/issues/33#issuecomment-559089027

Also, does the user you use to connect to the remote Windows node (defined in your rundeck node definition) have access to that SharePoint module?

Can you verify that the account that runs the process on the server has access to the Microsoft.Online.SharePoint.PowerShell module? Login to the system as the user and run Get-Module Microsoft.Online.SharePoint.PowerShell -ListAvailable
If that doesn't return anything, add the module's installation folder to the user's PSModulePath environment variable.

yes, and I got a return.
ModuleType Version    Name                                ExportedCommands

Binary     16.0.25... Microsoft.Online.SharePoint.Powe... {New-SPOListFileVersionBatchDeleteJob, Remove-SPOListFileVersionBatchDeleteJob, Get-SPOListF...
This means that the module is already installed in the server.
